# Mostrar Imagem no DataTable asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou com problemas para exibir uma Imagem no datatable na minha aplicação.
Eu recebo o nome da imagem mas ela não exibe.

```html
 "columns": [
                    { "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Name", "name": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "CPF", "name": "CPF", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "City", "title": "City", "name": "ContactName", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Adress", "name": "Adress", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "OcupnationName", "name": "OcupnationName", "autoWidth": true },
                    {
                        
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {

                            return '<img src="'+ full.Picture +'" style="width:150px; height:150px;" />';
                           
                        }
                
                    },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/Employee/Details/' + full.Id + '">Info</a>';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/Employee/AddOrEdit/' + full.Id + '">Edit</a>';
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + row.Id + "'); >Delete</a>";
                        }
                    },

                ]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No `full.Picture` deveria vir só `/Content/Fotos/images.jpg`, o `~` deveria sair da li porque não é renderizado pelo servidor e sim por javascript. Poderia tentar entao `full.Picture.substring(1)`

Comment: Obrigado era só esse bentido "~" mesmo, fiz como falou e deu certo.